# Probability of flipping coins

Tags: probability

How many times do you have to flip a coin to get a probability of 60% or higher to get 3 heads straight in a row?

I know how to get the probability by simply counting the number of favourable outcomes/total number of outcomes. However, I am confused to do this working backwards.

Comment: Do you want exactly 3 in a row? Or can it be 4 or more?

Comment: What have you done on this?  Can you compute the probability of success if you flip the coin 5 times, say?

Comment: @saulspatz. For 5 times. Total number of outcomes will be 2^5= 32 whereas favourable outcomes will be 5 choose 2 = 10. Therefore 10/32 or 5/16

Comment: That isn't the probability of success, though.  I was trying to suggest that you figure out what the favorable outcomes are for some small numbers of tosses, and see if that helps you.

Comment: The question of [jodds](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/212426/jdods) is still pending: "Do you want exactly 3 in a row? Or can it be 4 or more?"

Comment: @callculus I would say that if you get four heads in a row, you certainly get 3 heads is a row.

Comment: @jdods exactly 3 heads in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not straightforward to solve this problem combinatorially.

Say you have $n$ tosses of a fair coin.

Consider the running length of heads from the tail of the sequence, $\ell(n)$. I.e. is the sequence ends in `THT`, the running length is zero, if `THH` - the running length is 2, etc.

Let $p_0(n)$ denote the probability that the $\ell(n) = 0$, and we have not yet observed any sequence of 3 or more heads. Let $p_1(n)$ be the probability that $\ell(n)=1$, and that we have not yet observed the target subsequence, similarly define $p_2(n)$.

Let $p_3(n)$ denote probability that we have observed the sequence of 3 heads in a row.

Clearly $p_0(0) = 1$ and $p_1(0)=p_2(0)=p_3(0) = 0$.

Considering growing the sequence by a single coin toss, if the coin turns tails from any state where have not yet observed 3 or more heads, the running length plummets to zero:
$$
     p_{n+1}(0) = \frac{1}{2} p_n(0) + \frac{1}{2} p_n(1) + \frac{1}{2} p_n(2)
$$
Otherwise, if the coin turns head, the running length increments by 1:
$$
     p_{n+1}(1) = \frac{1}{2} p_n(0)
$$
$$
p_{n+1}(2) = \frac{1}{2} p_n(1)
$$
We reach the event of interest by either getting a head after previously seeing two heads, thus reaching the target event for the firth time, or if have already seen it earlier in the sequence.
$$
   p_{n+1}(3) = p_n(3) + \frac{1}{2} p_{n}(2)
$$

The problem is to find the smallest $n$, such that $p_3(n) > \tfrac{3}{5}$.

To solve this system of linear difference equations, the folk lore is to use sequence generating functions, for $k=0,1,2,3$:

$$
     g_k(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n p_n(k)
$$

Multiplying equations by $z^{n+1}$ and summing from 0 to $\infty$:
$$
    g_{0}(z) - p_0(0) = \frac{z}{2} \left(g_0(z) + g_1(z) + g_2(z)\right)
$$
$$
    g_{1}(z) - p_1(0) = \frac{z}{2} g_0(z)
$$
$$
    g_{2}(z) - p_2(0) = \frac{z}{2} g_1(z)
$$
$$
    g_{3}(z) - p_3(0) = z g_3(z) + \frac{z}{2} g_2(z)
$$

Taking into account initial probabilities $p_0(0)=1$ and $p_1(0)=p_2(0)=p_3(0)=0$ and solving this linear system for $g_3(z)$:

$$
g_3(z) =\frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{z^3}{(1-z) \left(1 - \tfrac{1}{2} z - \frac{1}{4} z^2 -\tfrac{1}{8} z^3\right)}
$$

Expanding the generating function around zero:

$$
  g_3(z) = \frac{z^3}{8}+\frac{3 z^4}{16}+\frac{z^5}{4}+\frac{5 z^6}{16}+\frac{47 z^7}{128}+\frac{107 z^8}{256}+\frac{119 z^9}{256}+\frac{65 z^{10}}{128}+\frac{1121 z^{11}}{2048}+\frac{2391 z^{12}}{4096}+\frac{79
   z^{13}}{128}+O\left(z^{14}\right)
$$

The first coefficient exceeding $60%$ corresponds to order 13, with approximate value being 61.72%

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this except numerically.  For a natural number $n,$

let $a_{n,0}$ be the number of $n$-bit binary strings that end in $0$ and do not contain three consecutive $1$ bits;

let $a_{n,1}$ be the number of $n$-bit binary strings that end in $01$ and do not contain three consecutive $1$ bits;

let $a_{n,2}$ be the number of $n$-bit binary strings that end in $11$ and do not contain three consecutive $1$ bits;

let $a_{n}$ be the number of $n$-bit binary strings that  do not contain three consecutive $1$ bits, so that $$a_n=a_{n,0}+a_{n,1}+a_{n,2}.$$

We have $$
a_{n+1,0}=a_n,\\
a_{n+1,1}=a_{n,0},\\
a_{n+1,2}=a_{n,1},$$

since we can append a $0$ to any $n$-bit $111$-free binary string and get a $111-$free $n+1$-bit binary string that ends in $0$, but to get a string that ends in $01$ we must append $1$ to a string that ends in $0$, and to get a $111$-free string that ends in $11$ we must append $1$ to a string that ends in $01$.

Then I wrote a little python script to compute the probability of a $111$-free string:

```
a0 = [0, 1, 2, 4]
a1 = [0, 1, 1, 2]
a2 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
a= [0,2,4,7]
for n in range(4,15):
    a2.append(a1[-1])
    a1.append(a0[-1])
    a0.append(a[-1])
    a.append(a0[-1]+a1[-1]+a2[-1])

prob=[an/2**n for n, an in enumerate(a)]
for n in range(15):
    print(n, a[n], prob[n])
```

This produced the output:

```
0 0 0.0
1 2 1.0
2 4 1.0
3 7 0.875
4 13 0.8125
5 24 0.75
6 44 0.6875
7 81 0.6328125
8 149 0.58203125
9 274 0.53515625
10 504 0.4921875
11 927 0.45263671875
12 1705 0.416259765625
13 3136 0.3828125
14 5768 0.35205078125
```

We want the smallest $n$ that makes the probability less than $40\%,$ so we take $n=13,$ which gives a probability of $61.71875\%$ of at least $3$ heads in a row.